# Iterating through Huggingface tokenizer with remainder

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

Transformer models have maximum token limits.  If I want to substring my text to fit within that limit, what is the generally accepted way?

Due to the treatment of special characters, it isn't the case that the tokenizer maps its tokens to something amenable to looping.  Naively:

```
subst = " ".join(mytext.split(" ")[0:MAX_LEN])
```

would let me loop through chunks with something like:

```
START = 0
i = 0
substr = []
while START+MAX_LEN < len(mytext.split(" ")):
  substr[i] = " ".join(mytext.split(" ")[START:START+MAX_LEN])
  START = START + MAX_LEN
  i = i + 1
  tokens = tokenizer(text)
```

However, `" ".join(mytext.split(" ")[0:MAX_LEN])` is not equal to the length given by `tokenizer(text)`.

You can see the difference below:

```
>>> from transformers import LongformerTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')

>>> mytext = "This is a long sentence. " * 2000 # about 10k tokens

>>> len(mytext.split(" "))
10001

>>> encoded_input = tokenizer(mytext) 
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (12003 > 4096). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
```

What is the function argument to `tokenizer` or if none available, the generally accepted iteration procedure for longer documents?

Comment: The [sliding window approach](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/66#issuecomment-436378461) is the generally accepted approach to process longer documents because simply splitting your text would remove context from the words on the edge. An example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62598130/pytorch-error-runtimeerror-index-out-of-range-tried-to-access-index-512-out-o/62616138#62616138).